# Reduced twisted $C^*$-algebra and twisted crossed product

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Let $G$ be a discrete group. Is it possible to represent $C^*_r(G, \sigma)$, the reduced twisted group $C^*$-algebra as a twisted crossed product?

Comment: Couldn’t you just take the trivial action on a singleton?

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić $C^*_r(G, \sigma) = C^*_r(G) \rtimes_{\sigma}\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Rather, $C^\ast_r(G,\sigma) = G \ltimes_{\sigma,r} \mathbb{C}$, but yes. This is a standard observation in the untwisted case, and it should carry through here too.

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić Thank you very much. I haven't had this observation in mind.